# The nilradical of $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Prove that the nilradical of $\mathbb{Z}_m$  is the set $\{0\}$ if and only if $m$ is not divided by any square of a prime number.

Here is my attemt for one part of the problem:

Let $N(\mathbb{Z}_m)=\{0\}$ and suppose that there exists a prime $p$ such that $p^2|m$.

Then $m=sp^2$. I took the element $[ps]\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ for which we have that $[ps] \neq [0]$ and $ps<m$.

We see that $[ps]^2=0$ thus $N(\mathbb{Z}_m) \neq \{0\}$ deriving a contradiction.

Is this part of the proof correct?

Can someone help me to prove the other part  of the statement?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's correct. For the other part, you can use Chinese Remainder Theorem, or at least break down $m\mid (x^2-x)$ into $p\mid (x^2-x)$ for all prime divisors $p\mid m$.

Comment: i must solve it without the chinese remainder theorem..

Comment: Which is why I also mentioned how to do it without namedropping CRT.

Comment: yes but i what do you denote as x?

Comment: Sorry I meant $x^2$ not $x$. (I was thinking of idempotents for some reason.) In any ring, if there is a nilpotent element, then there is an element that squares to $0$. Although even this isn't even necessary for the exercise. Suppose $m$ is squarefree and $x^k\equiv 0$ mod $m$, or in other words $m\mid x^k$. Then $p\mid x^k$ for each prime $p\mid m$, so $p\mid x$ for each $p$, so $m\mid x$, so $x$ is $0$ mod $p$.

Comment: (Err, that should read "I meant $x^2$ not $x^2-x$." Blargh.)

Comment: Because of the fact that $(p_1....p_n)=1$ for all $p_i$ prime factors of $m$ we have that $x=0modm$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1218330/prove-that-0-is-a-radical-ideal-in-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-iff-n-is-squar and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116999/how-to-find-the-nilpotent-elements-of-mathbbz-prod-p-in-i.